# Images in app_offline file

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to use an image with an app_offline file? I'd like to keep the app_offline looking like the rest of the website - same header, etc, which includes an image.

I did try finding a way to do this but I can't seem to do so.  The forum posts that I've ran across say it's not possible, since the app_offline forces all requests (even those for images and css) to redirect to the app_offline page,  but I'm hoping that someone here will have an answer.  Obviously, I can embed the css into the HTML, rather than pointing to the site's .css file, but I'm not sure how to get around the image issue.

Comment: I'm wondering if you tried embedding it as a resource?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting.  To get at an embedded resource, I'd need server-side code, right?"  But an app_offline.htm file does not have server-side code...  if I'm misunderstanding, please let me know and I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You're right... and Aracas' suggestion seems to be well worth a shot.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could try base64 encoding the image, ie.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,BASE64STRINGHERE" width="80" height="15" />
```

The reason you need to do it like this is that IIS sees the image as a request and app_offline.htm being present in the root is telling IIS to redirect ALL requests therefore this includes any MIME types from images to music etc

Comment: That just might work.  Hang on while I try it out.  I'll accept this answer if it works.

Comment: I added "the word "base64" to my Bing search  http://www.bing.com/search?q=app_offline+base64+image&form=CMDTDF&pc=CMDTDF&src=IE-SearchBox  and came up with a link explaining exactly how to do it.  THANK YOU!  http://pbodev.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/app_offline-htm-with-an-image-yes-we-can/

Comment: No problems, glad i could assist :-)

Comment: Yep.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks again.

Comment: And here is a website which can convert the image to string easily http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create

Comment: +1 You saved me, but i don't understand why image in url not work in app_offline.htm?? can anyone know?

Comment: @QMaster It's because IIS sees the image as a request and app_offline.htm being present in the root is telling IIS to redirect ALL requests therefore this includes any MIME types from images to music etc, hope that helps?

Comment: @Tur Thanks so much. I'd be so curious about that. +1 again :)